# mongo db query aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

Here is my data: in mongodb

```
db.population.insertMany([
    {
        "country" :"India",
        "state" : [
            {"Punjab" : { 
                            "male" : 50 ,
                            "female" : 50
                        }
            }, 
            {"Haryana" : { 
                            "male" : 150 ,
                            "female" : 140
                        }
            }, 
            {"UP" : { 
                            "male" : 120 ,
                            "female" : 160
                        }
            },
        ]
    }, {
        "country" :"Shri lanka",
        "state" : [
            {"Eastern" : { 
                            "male" : 30 ,
                            "female" : 40
                        }
            }, 
            {"North Central" : { 
                            "male" : 250 ,
                            "female" : 240
                        }
            }, 
            {"Uva" : { 
                            "male" : 120 ,
                            "female" : 260
                        }
            },
        ]
    }

])
```

I want this ans from  query result

```
Country : "shri lanka", "state" : "Eastern", total: 70
Country : "North Central", "state" : "Eastern", total: 490
Country : "Uva", "state" : "Eastern", total: 380
Country : "Haryana", "state" : "Punjab", total: 190
Country : "India", "state" : "Punjab", total: 100
```

And this one also

```
   Country : "India",  total: 500  total sum
   Country : "shri lanka",  total: 2541 total sum
```

Answer (score 0):

For first ans

```
db.population.aggregate([
  {$unwind:"$state"},
  {$project:{"country":1,"state":{$objectToArray: "$state"}}},
  {$unwind:"$state"}, 
  {$project:{"country":"$country","state":"$state.k",
  "total":{$sum:["$state.v.male","$state.v.female"]}}},
  { $group: { _id: "$country" , "total" : {$sum: "$total"}}}
])
```

for 2 ans

```
db.population.aggregate([
  {$unwind:"$state"},
  {$project:{"country":1,"state":{$objectToArray: "$state"}}},
  {$unwind:"$state"}, 
  {$project:{"country":"$country","state":"$state.k",
  "total":{$sum:["$state.v.male","$state.v.female"]}}},
  { $group: { _id: "$country" , "total" : {$sum: "$total"}}}
])
```

Comment: you can combine them in 1 query also using `$unionWith` with pipeline, your schema needs change to not store data on fields, fields are for the schema not for data, if you put data things get more complicated, probably that why you were stuck

Comment: please let me know this

Comment: see $unionWIth docs, its simple you just write the second pipeline inside the unionWith pipeline, if you mean the schena i think you need somehting like `states = [{name :kansas, population : {male : 50, female :100}}]`